# Avocado Pit Questions

Tags: avocado, dryness

I'm fairly new to gardening, planting, and whatnot. But I did get an avocado from my local farmers market. (It was organic.)

But I took the pit out, I followed all the steps on basically all the tutorials I've watched/read. Except for peeling the skin of the avocado pit. Half of the tutorials said to take it off, and half said not to.

And recently the top has been getting a little dry, is that okay? And will the plant germinate, while the top half (out of the water) is dry? Should I keep the top half, not moist but wet?

[image: Here is the pit]

Comment: The reason I started this was to learn patience. But thanks for the info!

Comment: You are doing just fine, great for patience and learning also time goes by fast.  I would use distilled water, not tap water but you should be seeing roots soon...like a few weeks?

Comment: I 'planted' these a few days ago, so yeah weeks until the roots.

Comment: I would get distilled water.  Tap water has chlorine as well as fluoride.  Not conducive for growing plants!  Don't worry about the top drying out.  The moisture evaporating from the water in your glasses will be enough.  Patience, grins!  But get rid of the tap water.  All tap water is different but all tap water should be used just for washing not for biologicals nor botanicals...including YOU!

Comment: Yeah, you need to have patience. From my own experience with these kind of experiments, I had better results peeling the skin of the pit before putting them in water (like you say some tutorials advice this).